# How to make a listview appearing from bottom or top?

Tags: android, listview, animation, baseadapter

List view with an base adapter.

Please guide me where what animation to add to make a listview appear from bottom to top.
or top to bottom.

I want to show whole items at set adapter and fit to its display.

like list have three pages thn, on set adapter it show show 3rd page content and scholl up to top and fits to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

in `ListView` xml

Comment: thanks for help. but the list is now showing end of list.
i want to make it exactly like this at fist time, but after appearing from bottom it should scroll to top. i have tried smoothscrollto() but it is not showing effect i want.